# Using the MacLaurin Series for $e^z$ for $(1+z)^\alpha\mid\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

Say we let $f\left(z\right) = \left(1+z\right)^\alpha$ for complex $\alpha$. We know that

$$\left(1+z\right)^\alpha = e^{\alpha\log\left(1+z\right)}.$$

which can, of course, be made single-valued by taking the branch cut $\left\{z\in\mathbb{R},z\leq -1\right\}$ and taking the principal branch of the complex logarithm. From here, one can recall the following MacLaurin expansion

$$e^z=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{z^n}{n!} = 1+z+\dfrac{z^2}{2}+\cdots\,\,\,\,\text{for $\left|z\right|<\infty$}$$

and plug in $z\equiv \alpha\,\mathrm{Log}\left(1+z\right)$ ($\mathrm{Log}$ being the principal branch) to get something like

$$e^{\alpha\,\mathrm{Log}\left(1+z\right)}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{\left[\alpha\,\mathrm{Log}\left(1+z\right)\right]^n}{n!} = 1+\alpha\,\mathrm{Log}\left(1+z\right)+\dfrac{\left(\alpha\,\mathrm{Log}\left(1+z\right)\right)^2}{2}+\cdots \,\,\,\,\text{for $\left|z\right|<1$}$$

Meanwhile, we can simply "directly" compute the MacLaurin expansion by taking the derivatives of $f$ (i.e. the standard computation for the Taylor series) to instead obtain something like

$$(1+z)^\alpha = 1 + \alpha z + \dfrac{\alpha\left(\alpha-1\right)}{2!}z^2+\cdots\,\,\,\,\text{for $\left|z\right|<1$}$$

Since the MacLaurin expansion has to be unique and I suppose the direct derivative approach is very likely correct, why doesn't the exponential substitution work?

Comment: I think if you substitute the Taylor expansion for $\text{Log}(1+z)$ in your first answer, it will be right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A MacLaurin series is, by definition, a series of the form $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n$ where each $a_n$ is a constant.  If $U$ is an open ball centered at $0$ and $f:U\to\mathbb{C}$, then there is at most one sequence $(a_n)$ such that $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n$ for all $z\in U$; this is what "uniqueness of MacLaurin series" means.  Your expression $$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{\left[\alpha\,\mathrm{Log}\left(1+z\right)\right]^n}{n!}$$ is not a MacLaurin series (it does not have the form $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n$), so it does not contradict the uniqueness of MacLaurin series.